# Django override bulk_create

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to override bulk_create method? I try this

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField()

    def bulk_create(self, objs, batch_size=None):
        #do something
        return super(SomeModel, self).bulk_create(objs, batch_size)
```

But it doesn't work. When I run this code

```
SomeModel.objects.bulk_create(objects_list)
```

It's create new objects, but it doesn't use my override bulk_create method. Is it possible to override bulk_create? And how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`bulk_create` is a method on the `Manager` class, and `SomeModel.objects` is an instance of `Manager`. You need to subclass `Manager` and override the method there, then add the manager to `SomeModel`:

```
class SomeModelManager(models.Manager):
    def bulk_create(self, objs, batch_size=None, ignore_conflicts=False):
        ...

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    objects = SomeModelManager()
```

See the documentation on [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) for more information.