# How to add record after bulk_create objs in django？

Tags: django

I want to add a record for each model object that created by `bulk_create` method of `django`, how can I make it work?

It seems rewriting `save` method of model doesn't work.

```
# WarningAccountsSpend
class WarningAccountsSpend(models.Model):
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    spend_cap = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='spend cap', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    balance = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_spend_over_yesterday = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    growth_rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_create_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_violated = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    spend = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'warning_accounts_spend'
        unique_together = (('account_id', 'date'),)
        ordering = ["-spend"]

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        # add operate log 
        # It seems not work here
        super(WarningAccountsSpend, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None)
```

```
# bulk_create model obj

WarningAccountsSpend.objects.bulk_create([...], ignore_conflicts=True)
```

How can I add some other operation for object that I bulk created.

> **Update  my trial so far**

I override `_insert` and `update` method of class `Queryset` which is the basic operation for `bulk_create` and `bulk_update`.

It worked but `_insert` itself is a `private` method. So my trial seems not to be good. Any better way to make this?

Great thanks.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.manager import BaseManager
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet



class AddLogQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def _insert(self, objs, fields, return_id=False, raw=False, using=None, ignore_conflicts=False):
        # bulk_create base operation
        obj_id = super(AddLogQuerySet, self)._insert(objs, fields, return_id=True, raw=raw, using=using, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)
        if obj_id != 0:
            # add add record for each obj created by bulk_create
            ...

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        # bulk_update base operation
        # add add record for each obj updated by bulk_update        
        ...


class AddLogManager(BaseManager.from_queryset(AddLogQuerySet)):
    ...


class WarningAccountsSpend(models.Model):
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    spend_cap = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='spend cap', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    balance = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_spend_over_yesterday = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    growth_rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_create_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_violated = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    spend = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = AddLogManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'warning_accounts_spend'
        unique_together = (('account_id', 'date'),)
        ordering = ["-spend"]

    
    # save and update operation for single obj created or updated
    def save(self, user_id, log_type, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):

        obj_id = self.pk
        origin_obj = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). You don't have to call `save()` to update your database.

> The model’s `save()` method will not be called, and the `pre_save` and `post_save` signals will not be sent.

After you call `bulk_create()`, all the records will be saved to the database, if you want to update some fields please see `bulk_update()` in the documentation link attached above.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  But you're probobly misunderstanding my attemption. What I want to do is add some operation according to the obj created, not just update itself.

Comment: Could you please tell me which kind of operations are you willing to do?

Comment: I'm going to `bulk_create` or `bulk_update` some spend data. And I want to record the `create, update time` of each object created or updated at the same time

Comment: If you mean by your `created_time` model, I strongly recommend you to retrieve and set them before `bulk_create()`. Anyway, if the recording time is extremely sensitive, I suggest you to override `bulk_create()`. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809910/django-override-bulk-create) might be able to help you.

Comment: I tried with overriding base `_insert` and `update` method of class `Queryset`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#)  which is the base opearation of `bulk_create` and `bulk_update`. And thanks again for your patience